# Firefox hangs after upgrade to version 3.6.11

Tags: firefox

I just upgraded firefox to version 3.6.11 and after the installation was done I got the message that adobe flash player 10.1 needs to be downloaded so I did (even though the flash player I had before upgrading firefox was 10.1 but I reinstalled it coz I thought that since firefox got updated so it needs the plugin to be installed again) and after that whenever I open any website with flash in it (like youtube or facebook games), firefox hangs and stops responding. I don't know if this is related to firefox upgrade or the flash player.

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [on the Firefox support forum](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/717337) that tracks the problem down to the plugin-container.exe file

> #### Steps to stop plugin-container.exe process:
>
> 1. Open Firefox web browser.
> 2. Type **about:config** in the address bar and press **Enter** key.
> 3. A warning will appear. Ignore it and press the **“I’ll be careful, I promise!”** button.
> 4. In the Filter field type **dom.ipc.** Six preferences will appear for the filter dom.ipc.
> 5. Ignore first and last preferences (dom.ipc.plugins.enabled and dom.ipc.plugins.timeoutSecs). Toggle (double-click) each of the four remaining preferences to change the value from **“true”** to **“false“**.
> 6. That’s it.

Above steps to fix from [TechnoGadge](http://www.technogadge.com/how-to-stop-firefox-plugin-container-exe-process/).

Comment: In future, quote the steps with a link back to the source. Link only answers are no answers at all.